# What is the file permission of /etc/shadow in CentOS?

Tags: files, permissions, etc

What is the default file permission of /etc/shadow in CentOS? Is there any difference in the default file permission of /etc/shadow in previous versions of CentOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting observation; the only concrete evidence I could find, so far, is [this SCAP mailing list thread](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/scap-security-guide/2012-August/001457.html) talking about the change from RHEL5's default permissions of **0400** to RHEL6's default of **0**.  You can also observe that in the list of Common Configuration Enumartions on the Working Group's [now-archived website](http://cce.mitre.org/lists/cce_list.html).

Answer (score 0):

> The shadow file is specifically designed to be read ONLY by root. The
>   point in this file is to prevent people from seeing your encrypted
>   passwords because there are commands like "crack" than can figure out
>   many passwords from their encrypted values. Prior to introduction of
>   the shadow file the encrypted passwords were stored in /etc/passwd and
>   if they weren't properly formed were very easy to break.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/

> /etc/shadow file stores actual password in encrypted format for user's
>   account with additional properties related to user password i.e. it
>   stores secure user account information. All fields are separated by a
>   colon (:) symbol. It contains one entry per line for each user listed
>   in /etc/passwd file